# boost mpi equivalent of status.MPI_SOURCE

Tags: mpi, boost-mpi

is there a `boost::MPI` equivalent of the following C MPI code? I'm trying to port the following standard MPI code which is a basic master slave template found [here](http://www.lam-mpi.org/tutorials/one-step/ezstart.php). Following from the boost mpi documentation theres only 3 parameters , for an mpi_send or mpi_recv rank, tag and buffer.

```
while (work != NULL) {

    /* Receive results from a slave */

    MPI_Recv(&result,           /* message buffer */
             1,                 /* one data item */
             MPI_INT,        /* of type double real */
             MPI_ANY_SOURCE,    /* receive from any sender */
             MPI_ANY_TAG,       /* any type of message */
             MPI_COMM_WORLD,    /* default communicator */
             &status);          /* info about the received message */

    /* Send the slave a new work unit */

    MPI_Send(&work,             /* message buffer */
             1,                 /* one data item */
             MPI_INT,           /* data item is an integer */
             status.MPI_SOURCE, /* to who we just received from */
             WORKTAG,           /* user chosen message tag */
             MPI_COMM_WORLD);   /* default communicator */

    /* Get the next unit of work to be done */

    work = get_next_work_item();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [boost.MPI documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.c_mapping):

- `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` becomes `any_source`
- `MPI_ANY_TAG` becomes `any_tag`

The `communicator::recv()` method returns an instance of the [status](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/status.html) class that provides all the information that you need:

- `status.MPI_SOURCE` is returned by `status::source()`
- `status.MPI_TAG` is returned by `status::tag()`

It also provides two cast operators to covert its content to `MPI_Status` structure.